# NameError: global name 'isdigit' is not defined

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, nltk

I've looked at similar questions on SO, but I don't think anything is similar to this one. But, maybe I am wrong and that's why I am here. This is on a Mac. Python version is 2.7.6.

Trying to get the syllables in word, for all the words in a line.

Wrote a module 'wordfunc.py' which has this:

```
from nltk.corpus import cmudict as cmud
import nltk

d=cmud.dict()

def parse_line(line):
        return nltk.word_tokenize(line)

def ns(word):
        if word.lower() not in d:
                return -1
        else:
#               print lcase
                return [len(list(y for y in x if isdigit(y[-1]))) for x in d[word.lower()]]
```

And the main program test.py has this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wordfunc
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print "No arguments"
    exit()

## read a stream first
try:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as entrywound:
        for line in entrywound:
            words = wordfunc.parse_line(line)

            ## print word and number of syllables per word
            for w in words:
                print 'Word: '+w
                print 'Sysllables: '
                print wordfunc.ns(w)
except IOError:
    print "Unable to open file. Exiting!"
    exit(1)
```

When I run this program with a file, I get this error:

```
./test.py /tmp/test
Word: quick
Sysllables: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print wordfunc.ns(w)
  File "/Users/sid/Cave/scripts/wordfunc.py", line 14, in ns
    return [len(list(y for y in x if isdigit(y[-1]))) for x in d[word.lower()]]
  File "/Users/sid/Cave/scripts/wordfunc.py", line 14, in <genexpr>
    return [len(list(y for y in x if isdigit(y[-1]))) for x in d[word.lower()]]
NameError: global name 'isdigit' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? I mean, isn't `isdigit` already a global function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's a method of strings.  I suspect you want `y[-1].isdigit()`.

Comment: thanks. that works like a charm. Did the usage for isdigit() change at some point in python or has it always been like this?

Comment: @SidCarter I don't remember seeing anything like that, and I've been using Python since the early 2.x days, but human memories are faulty and machine memories are hard to query (especially when they yield questions similar to yours).

Comment: I ask because I see this usage everywhere when used with nltk.
one example - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nltk-users/mCOh_u7V8_I/HsBNcLYM54EJ

thank you, either way.

Comment: @SidCarter: You can see at the top of that example that they did `from curses.ascii import isdigit`, importing such a function from another library.  But there's no need to do so since it already exists as a string method.

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit()` is a method on a string, like this: `'3'.isdigit()`.

Try changing your code to `y[-1].isdigit()`.